# Error Message on Event Registration - Known Issues?

Tags: civievent, error, registration, textarea

Using CiviCRM 4.6.28 and Drupal 7
Using Custom Profiles in CiviEvents
No Payments
Not Able to Recreate

We have an ongoing issue of error messages after applicants submit a CiviEvent registration form.
[image]

We noticed this started to happen when we added questions with the formate of Rich Text Editor.  Is this a known issue?

According to our consultants the issue is a time out issue.  Is this a known issue?  If it is a time out issue, does someone know how to make a change to the back end to not have the system time out?

We have not been able to recreate the issue.  We have changed all of our questions back over to text only fields in the hope that is the issue.

Thank you

Comment: did changing your questions back to text-only resolve the issue?

Comment: This is a good question!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: I've seen this before and fixed it.  Sadly, I can't remember what caused it other then I think it was a catch 22.  The id doesn't exist until the person exists and something was trying update a custom field that didn't exist or the person existed but the custom field didn't.  The tracing and back trace as Jon G say will point to that.  You might look at the custom fields and default values I assume you are using for your questions.  I just tried to reproduce this and couldn't, so this comment is probably pointless.  Grasping at straws, are your questions before or after the registration?